# :active pseudo-class not triggered for input[type=button] on IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to style an `input[type="button"]` and it seems that when I click on the label IE (9 in my case; I don't care for lower versions) doesn't apply the `:active` style. Everything works beautifully on Chrome and Firefox and also in IE if I click outside of the label. I had no luck in finding any clues to what might be the problem.

A `<button>` doesn't have this problem, so I guess there's something special about the other button's label, but what? And is there any workaround?

The problem is demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/Kmved/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting find there. To answer the first question, "why?": unfortunately, the CSS spec leaves the semantics of `:active` [entirely up to the browser vendor](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

> CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how
>   the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements
>   react to user events or not, and different devices and UAs may have
>   different ways of pointing to, or activating elements.

Now I would consider this a bug in IE (and expect it to be fixed in IE10 perhaps), but the letter of the law says that this is perfectly acceptable and tough luck to you.

To answer the second question (workaround?): well, you said it yourself. Use a `<button>` instead; as a bonus you get the option of placing any type of content inside the button in addition to simple text.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice and I need to style both input[type="button"] and <button>. Tough luck on me, exactly :).

Comment: @civilu: It's dirty, but perhaps use JS to dynamically replace the input controls with corresponding button controls on page load? Hopefully noone will ever know.

Comment: The CSS I'm authoring should be part of a "theme" so I don't really control the context in which it will be used. I guess the behaviour on IE will have to be accepted as a limitation. Thanks for the answer and suggestion.